# Macintosh HD volume reduced after error during Bootcamp Partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, boot-camp, disk-space, disk-utility

I was creating a new partition with bootcamp assistant, when this screen came up:
[your computer restarted because of a problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyV3t.png)

When the computer was on again, I checked my disk utility and the Macintosh HD disk was smaller (180gb instead of 250gb) and there is no new partition. So 70gb of my volume has gone somewhere, and I don't know how to restore it since there was no extra partition created. The capacity still shows it's a 250gb disk, but the Macintosh HD partition is just 180gb.

Here's a screenshot of my disk utility:
[image]

I tried first aid in recovery mode, and repairing disk from single user mode, but nothing changed.
Any ideas what could I do? Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: This is probably a non-partitioned area on the hard disk now .For example, Windows does not display such areas.Probably you can resize your partition to the original volume.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a non-partitioned area. The question is how do I recover this area and use it to resize back to my original volume? I cannot do it through disk utility's partitions, because I don't have any. So far I haven't been able to find this missing 70gb anywhere.

Comment: unless you want to do some serious work in Terminal, your 'easy fix' is to get  [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) to either strip out all the broken GUID/MBR hybrid & expand the HFS+ partition back to full size.. or see if it can fix it in-situ [it's the only tool that can.]

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin. Paragon Hard Disk Manager stated that my core storage physical volume was unformatted. So I decrypted my disk and formatted it back again. After restarting I recovered my missing volume!!